# set expiration dates of elements loaded by other servers on my website

Tags: php, seo, server

I am trying to set expiration time of contents of my website so to increase website performance and have a good page speed insight.
I am able to set expiration time for elements that resides on my server but some of the elements which are loaded from other servers (CDN, social networking sites etc.) have "expiration not specified". Following is an example:

```
http://platform.twitter.com/…c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css (expiration not specified)
```

due to these elements, PageSpeed insight of google developer shows an error to fix "Leverage browser caching"
Below is the path for PageSpeed insight for reference:

```
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiwigo.com%2Fblog
```

how can I set the expiration for such elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about those assets. In some situations, like a "Tweet" button, you may be able to replace their JavaScript-based one with a static image and a link, but for the more dynamic plugins like a Facebook "Like" button, you won't be able to adjust PageSpeed's recommendations for third-party items.

Comment: but some of the contents do have expiration set.

Comment: @Deepakjha Yes. That's controlled by Twitter/Facebook/etc. and not you. For some assets, they set an expiration. For others, they don't. You can't do anything about which ones they do/don't.

Comment: because these elements have their expiration set on their own servers?

Comment: ok thanks, but if I download some of elements to my server will it have any consequences?

Comment: @Deepakjha Yes. First consequence: it won't work at all, because assets like `c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css` are loaded by the Twitter JavaScript code. Second consequence: you'd risk changes to Twitter/etc.'s systems breaking your hacked-together replacement buttons. Bottom line: stop caring about this, you can't fix it and they're not likely to be a significant performance impact anyways.